# Best practice of providing 'this' context to method in different class

Tags: javascript

I have 2 classes, one of them is a general utility class used by the entire application. I would like to reference the `this` property of the caller class in the callee utility class.

I am unsure what the best practice for this is.

I have provided an example of what I'm trying to do.

I one case I can use `.call` to provide the correct `this` context or I can pass `this` in as a function parameter.

```js
class Caller {

  doSomething() {
    Utility.calledMethod.call(this, 'paramStr');
    Utility.calledMethodWithThis(this, 'paramStr');
  }

  doAnotherThing(param) {
    console.log(param);
  }
}

// Shared Class of utility methods used for entire application
class Utility {

  static calledMethod(param) {
    this.doAnotherThing(param);
  }

  static calledMethodWithThis(self, param) {
    self.doAnotherThing(param);
  }
}

const caller = new Caller();
caller.doSomething();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pvafedho/

Comment: Use `function.call()` -- that's what it's made for.

Comment: Does `Utility` need to know what `this` actually is? The usual way to do this is to simply pass the callback itself: `Utility.calledMethod.call(this.doAnotherThing, 'paramStr');` and `static calledMethod(callback, param) { callback(param); }`.

If `Utility` needs to have access to other methods in `Caller`, this smells like a whole different pattern. Maybe you can describe the context a bit more?

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a scenario where you can utilize a mixin.

Following the example from this page: https://javascript.info/mixins

Your code could look like this:

```
// Shared Class of utility methods used for entire application
let utilityMixin = {
  calledMethod(param) {
        this.doAnotherThing(param);
  }
}

class Caller {
  constructor() {
    this.mystring = 'hello!'  
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.calledMethod(this.mystring);
  }

  doAnotherThing(param) {
    console.log(param);
  }
}

Object.assign(Caller.prototype, utilityMixin );

const caller = new Caller();

caller.doSomething();
```